# MySQL ranking with grouping

Tags: mysql

I'm newbie, trying to rank students mark with different classes, my query follows:

```
SELECT Branch, Grade, Section, RollNo, FIrst_Name, Father_Name, Grand_Father_Name, AverageMark, rank 
FROM (
    SELECT Branch, Grade, Section, RollNo, FIrst_Name, Father_Name, Grand_Father_Name, AverageMark, @curRank := IF(@prevRank = AverageMark, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank,  @incRank := @incRank + 1,  @prevRank := AverageMark 
    FROM studentsaverage p, 
        ( SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1 ) r 
    ORDER BY AverageMark DESC
) s
```

[image]

The highlighted students rank is 4 instead of 1, because the student is from another school, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing to test my code actually but the problem with your code is that you don't verify if the branch is the same:

```
SELECT Branch,
       Grade,
       SECTION,
       RollNo,
       FIrst_Name,
       Father_Name,
       Grand_Father_Name,
       AverageMark,
       rank
FROM
    ( SELECT Branch,
             Grade,
             SECTION,
             RollNo,
             FIrst_Name,
             Father_Name,
             Grand_Father_Name,
             AverageMark,
             @curRank := IF(@curBranch = Branch ,IF(@prevRank = AverageMark, @curRank, @incRank),1) AS rank,
             @incRank := @incRank + 1,
             @prevRank := AverageMark,
             @curBranch = Branch
     FROM studentsaverage p,
         (SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1, @curBranch := NULL) r
     ORDER BY Branch, AverageMark DESC) s
```